# Existe alguma API para enviar mensagem pelo WhatsApp usando PHP?

Tags: php, whatsapp

Existe alguma API para enviar mensagem para o WhatsApp de uma pessoa usando PHP?

Comment: Se a API não estiver funcionando recomendo que leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/130096/3635

Comment: Resposta removida, pois viola os termos do WhatsApp. Boa sorte.

Comment: Oficialmente, não.
Mas tem os métodos alternativos, como esse aqui: https://whatsmate.github.io/2016-02-20-send-whatsapp-message-php/

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Enviar mensagem para WhatsAPP via sistema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130093/enviar-mensagem-para-whatsapp-via-sistema)

Comment: Você não precisa de PHP para isso, pode usar um link assim: `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone={SE_NUMERO_CELULAR}&text=SUA MENSAGEM&lang=pt_br` , veja esse [exemplo com número fake](https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=119123456789&text=SUA%20MENSAGEM&lang=pt_br).

Answer (score 11):

Bom exite sim uma api do WhatsApp link oficial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/overview

> O cliente da API do WhatsApp Business é compatível com um subconjunto de recursos fornecidos pelos aplicativos do WhatsApp que você já conhece do Android, do iOS, da Web e de outras plataformas, incluindo criptografia de ponto a ponto. A diferença é que esse aplicativo pode ser implantado em um servidor, fornecendo uma API local que permite a você enviar e receber mensagens programaticamente e integrar esse fluxo de trabalho aos seus próprios sistemas (CRMs, atendimento ao cliente etc.).
>
> Se você usar algo que não seja a API oficial do WhatsApp Business ou outras ferramentas oficiais do WhatsApp, reservamos o direito de limitar ou remover seu acesso ao WhatsApp, pois isso viola nossas políticas. Não use ferramentas de terceiros não autorizadas pelo WhatsApp para se comunicar no aplicativo.

Answer (score -1):

Não existe nenhuma API oficial para envio ou recebimento de mensagem do WhatsApp para nenhuma linguagem.

Você até pode encontrar algo que não seja oficial, mas não há garantia que irá funcionar para sempre, pois o WhatsApp trabalha fortemente para bloquear qualquer API de terceiros que faça isso.

Você pode ler um pouco mais sobre a politica do WhatsApp é tirar suas dúvidas.
https://www.whatsapp.com/legal