# Como integrar a aplicação com Whatsapp?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api, whatsapp

Queria saber se é possível integrar uma aplicação feita em C# com o Whatsapp?

Comment: Depois que o whats implementou a criptografia ponta a ponta, as API's de "terceiros" deixaram de funcionar, você também deve verificar que se você enviar muitas mensagens em um curto espaço de tempo o whats bloqueia como SPAM

Comment: Entendi, então se quisermos algo semelhante, terei de partir para o Telegram, mas o problema está no uso dele, bem menos que o what's app.

Comment: Antes dava para dar um insert na tabela `msgstore.db` com status `-1`, agora a mensagem fica criptografada na tabela chamada `_jobqueue-WhatsAppJobManager`, você pode fazer algo no whats (Fiz um bot através do `whatsweb`, e manipula as tabelas via adb).. O Envio é demorado para enviar a 10k de pessoas demora cerca de 5 horas com 1 smarthphone (até agora não bloqueou como SPAM)..

Comment: Existem empresas especializadas nesse tipo só dar uma buscada no google como `Whatsapp marketing`, mas acaba saindo mais caro do que enviar por SMS.., com relatórios de enviados, entregues e lidos...Não vou mandar os links aqui, senão vão pensar que estou fazendo propaganda kkk

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni, a razão da escolha do whats é que é bem mais barato que os SMS. Imagine enviar sms duas a três vezes por dia para mais de 11.000 clientes? É inviável financeiramente.

Comment: Na busca que estávamos fazendo o valor do disparo do whats é cerca de 0,12 enquanto para sms fica 0,08.. claro se pegar um pacote maior de envios do whats, deve ficar mais em conta mesmo.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Se você está tentando utilizar, ou já utiliza alguma API, pare, isso é CRIME!

**Não existe nenhuma API oficial** para envio ou recebimento de mensagem do WhatsApp para **nenhuma linguagem**, pelo menos até o momento atual dessa resposta.

Você até **pode** encontrar algo que não seja oficial, mas a garantia que irá funcionar na primeira vez e ficar funcionando é algo sem resposta, pois o WhatsApp trabalhar fortemente para **bloquear qualquer API de terceiros**.

Você pode ler um pouco mais sobre a [política do WhatsApp](https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/?l=pt_pt) e tirar suas dúvidas.

Somente uma ressalva, um comentário do próprio líder de desenvolvimento Brian Acton na conferência F8 do Facebook, traduzido:

> ...nós não temos planos para abrir o WhatsApp nesse momento...Não queremos incomodar nossos usuários com mensagens que eles não querem receber<sup>[1](https://www.quora.com/WhatsApp-Why-doesnt-WhatsApp-have-an-API)</sup>...

Por esse comentário é bem provável que não tenha uma API disponível durante um bom tempo.

#### Adendo

Como dito no próprio comentário, é possível ver que não existe possibilidade (até o momento) de uma API com funcionamento constante:

> Depois que o Whatsapp implementou a criptografia ponta a ponta, as API's de "terceiros" deixaram de funcionar. Você também deve verificar que se você enviar muitas mensagens em um curto espaço de tempo o Whatsapp irá bloquear como SPAM.

E no [próprio site dos termos de uso](https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/#terms-of-service), traduzido está escrito:

> Você não deve (ou auxiliar outros) a acessar, usar, copiar, adaptar, modificar, preparar trabalhos derivados com base, distribuir, licenciar, sublicenciar, transferir, exibir, executar ou, de outra forma, explorar nossos Serviços de maneiras inadmissíveis ou não autorizadas, ou em Maneiras que nos ocupam, nos prejudicam ou nos prejudicam, nossos serviços, sistemas, usuários ou outros, incluindo que você não deve diretamente ou através de meios automatizados:
>
> - (A) fazer engenharia reversa, alterar, modificar, criar trabalhos derivados, descompilar ou extrair código de nossos serviços;
> - (B) enviar, armazenar ou transmitir vírus ou outro código de computador prejudicial através ou em nossos Serviços;
> - (C) obter ou tentar obter acesso não autorizado aos nossos Serviços ou sistemas;
> - (D) interferir ou interromper a integridade ou o desempenho de nossos Serviços;
> - (E) criar contas para nossos Serviços através de meios não autorizados ou automatizados;
> - (F) coletar as informações sobre ou sobre os nossos usuários de forma inadmissível ou não autorizada;
> - (G) vender, revender, alugar ou cobrar pelos nossos Serviços;
> - (H) distribuir ou disponibilizar nossos Serviços através de uma rede onde eles podem ser usados ​​por vários dispositivos ao mesmo tempo.

#### Relacionado

- [Script que envie mensagem WhatsApp?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10110/script-que-envie-mensagem-whatsapp) - Apesar da resposta aceita (na época) funcionar, hoje em dia foi bloqueada também.
- [Enviar mensagem no Whatsapp usando PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51387/enviar-mensagem-no-whatsapp-usando-php)
- [Perguntas relacionadas ao Whatsapp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp)
- [Google Básico sobre API Whatsapp](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Why+whatsapp+doesn%27t+have+api&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw3OeSv5XVAhVLipAKHYloCGAQBQgjKAA&biw=1440&bih=790)
- [Algumas razões de fechamento da WhatsAPI](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI/blob/master/README.md)- Imagem<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kObTT.jpg)</sup>

Comment: Acho legal você pôr no início que isso fere gravemente a política de uso do WhatsApp.

Comment: @LINQ viu agora?

Comment: Boa. Essa frase da edição ficou ótima!

Comment: Muito boa a resposta, bem completa, só para deixar aqui também o `venomous0x`, na conta do github dele, ele deixou uma mensagem das complicações da API que ele estava disponibilizando. Pode ser lido [aqui](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: resposta bem completa

Comment: O Whatsapp liberou uma API para pequenos empresários: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api