# Existe alguma API Whatsapp "Oficial"

Tags: api, whatsapp

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma API oficial ou nao do whatsapp. Sei que existem empresas especializadas em disparos de mensagens via whatsapp, eu gostaria de saber como eles fazem, pois ja pesquisei outras threads [como essa] e [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51387/existe-alguma-api-para-enviar-mensagem-pelo-whatsapp-usando-php)[2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221557/como-integrar-a-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-whatsapp/221574#221574) que mostram que existia uma api que foi descontinuada por motivos legais, porem elas sao antigas e o numero de empresas que oferecem o servico de disparo em massa de mensagens por whatsapp aumentou bastante. Se uma api open source foi fechada por motivos legais, como empresas estao comercializando disparos e como elas fazem isso?

Comment: Sim existe uma API oficial: https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/reference

Comment: sim, essa eu ja conheco, estou perguntando somente Whatsapp. O whatsapp bussiness é outro produto

Comment: Relacionada: [Como integrar a aplicação com Whatsapp?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/221557/5878)

Comment: A pergunta é a mesma. Se julgar as respostas insuficientes, pode oferecer uma recompensa de "respostas desatualizadas".

Comment: Porem nas duas threads que coloquei de referencia nao responderam a pergunta, que é: como essas empresas fazem esses disparos? se isto é ilegal como elas ainda continuam ativas e uma api open-source foi fechada?

Comment: @Phill só lembrando que há uma diferença entre ser contra os termos de uso e ser ilegal. Se for seguir a risca os termos de uso, 90% das páginas do Facebook poderiam ser deletadas facilmente, só pra citar um exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Até onde sei,  [esta](https://chat-api.com/en/?lang=PT)  a mais usada pelas empresas. Já testei implementando códigos em PHP + JS e é um espetáculo, basta seguir a política de uso da api a risca e seguir os conselhos de quem já usou, pois para não ter o número bloqueado é preciso seguir algumas regrinhas...

Comment: Tão oficial que a forma de contato com eles é via Telegram :D Não, não é oficial e deve fazer uso de prática ilícita não autorizada pelos termos de uso do Whatsapp, podendo parar de funcionar a qualquer momento - e em casos mais graves serem processados e tirados do ar.

Comment: Então é isso que eu queria saber, mas como eles funcionam sem ter uma api oficial, entende? Existe alguma falha no whatsapp web que permite esse tipo de pratica algo do tipo?

Comment: Estas APIs não oficiais usam da técnica web scrapping. Estes dias estou estudando sobre isto e vi como devem fazer. Python e Selenium pra fazer a mágica.